# A ball collides with an inclined plane of angle $\alpha$ after falling through a distance h..

Tags: physics, self-learning

> If it movies horizontally after the impact, find the coefficient of restitution

[image]

Conserving momentum along line of impact 
$$v_1\cos\alpha=v_2\sin\alpha$$

$$v_2=v_1\cot \alpha$$
Therefore 
$$e=\frac{v_2\sin\alpha}{v_1\cos\alpha}$$
$$e=1$$ which doesn’t make sense, what am I doing wrong?

*This is a physics question, but since Physics SE doesn’t accept such questions, I am posting it on Math SE with the physics tag.*

Comment: Your formula conserves momentum parallel to the red line. Why do you want to do that? What about momentum parallel to the surface?

Comment: @DavidK I thought about that too, but why doesn’t this work. I feel that conceptually what I did is very wrong, but what about mathematically?

Comment: If you just randomly choose a formula and plug the quantities into it, why should you expect a good result? There is no sense using a formula unless you know why you should use that formula.

Comment: In this case you have one formula for coefficient of restitution in the form of a fraction, and in another formula you took the numerator and denominator of that fraction and set them equal, so of course the result will be $1$.

Comment: The directional momentum is conserved with net zero force along that direction. Note that, along the line of impact, the momentum is not conserved due to the non-zero impact force perpendicular to the surface. So, the equation you established is questionable. I concur with @DavidK that you should instead establish the momentum equation parallel to the inclined surface along whose direction the impact force is zero.

Comment: As I said, it very obvious that what I did was wrong, even I know it. But I just came bouncing back to this thing. I knew the parallel surface part, but was confused on why this didn't work. Since @quanto explained it well, my problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

To summarize and organize what has been said in comments, prior to the collision, the ball has velocity components

- $v_1\sin \theta$ parallel to the inclined plane,
- $v_1\cos \theta$ perpendicular to the inclined plane (toward the plane).

After the collision, the ball has velocity

- $v_2\cos \theta$ parallel to the inclined plane,
- $v_2\sin \theta$ perpendicular to the inclined plane (away from the plane).

The coefficient of restitution is the ratio of the two “perpendicular” velocities.

Presumably you are supposed to assume that momentum parallel to the surface is preserved, which implies that the component of velocity is conserved (since the moving mass is the same before and after).
This is a simplification, since a real-life ball would have been in contact with the surface for a non-zero amount of time, during which it would experience a frictional force parallel to the surface. But it’s a reasonable simplification.

Instead of setting the parallel velocities equal, however, you decided to write

$$v_1\cos \theta = v_2\sin \theta,
$$

which says the two perpendicular velocities are equal. Since $e$ is  defined as the ratio of these velocities, in effect you have decided to set $e$ to a ratio of equal quantities, which will always give a ratio of $1.$

Comment: Okay, here is another problem. The equation was arrived from conservation of momentum, and momentum is conserved both parallel and perpendicularly, is it not?

Comment: We already know the ball's momentum is not constant perpendicular to the plane, because it reverses direction. In order for the ball to bounce there must be exchange of momentum between the ball and the ground. And the ball's momentum is not completely reversed in this process--its magnitude decreases slightly. Otherwise a dropped ball would just keep bouncing to the same height over and over.